# Unable to access elements on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on an automation task but reached a road block. The website contains an element which I wish to click but I am unable to access it.

So this is the HTML of the button:

```
<div style="transform: translateX(1120px) translateY(0px); position: fixed; left: 0px;" title="Download selected item" tabindex="1" aria-disabled="false" role="button" class="cw-button download-button p2-toolbar-button" id="bu"><span class="title"></span></div>
```

It has various classes but the class `download-button` is unique to it.

Now when I execute `document.getElementsByClassName("download-button")` in the console, it returns an empty array rather than returning the element.

Here are a few screenshots as proof:

[image]

Also as you can see, I tried adding an `id` to the element and tried to use `getElementById` but even that doesn't work!

**NOTE** : I am running the commands in the console only after the page is completely loaded.

So how do I access such elements?

Comment: where are you accessing the element from? make sure that you access the element after the complete page load

Comment: @xFighter  am executing the getElement from the browser itself after the page is completely loaded.

Comment: Are you sure the element is not in a separate iframe?

Comment: @SGSVenkatesh Just checked, there is only one iframe

Comment: You cannot access elements in a iframe. Is this element inside that iframe?

Comment: var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

Comment: *Also as you can see, I tried adding an id...*  - **No, I don't see that you did, but I'll take your word for it** - *...to the element and tried to use getElementById but even that doesn't work!* - **So you can hard code an id to said button?  Ok, I see `#bu`...hmm**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to assume that this button is on the other page that's in the iframe (i.e. child page). First your situation must meet the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) requirements:

Parent page (the page that hosts the iframe) and the child page (the page within the iframe) **both must have the same:**

> - Protocol: either `http://` or `https://`||| `https://`
>
>   ---
> - Sub-domain: `www`, `app`, `mail`, `s3`...  ||| `https://www.`
>
>   ---
> - Domain: `amazonaws.com`, `google.com` ||| `https://www.google.com`
>
>   ---
> - Port: `8080`, `443`, `21`, *........................||| `https://www.google.com:80`

`* port is required only if it's specified

**SO IF**...

> ...you have both pages with matching protocol, sub-domain, and domain you can access the iframe...

**IF NOT**...

> ...then you'll at least need access to the child page...

**IF NOT**...

> ...you have no business trying to tamper with a website that you do not have the proper credentials to.

The following Snippet demonstrates how to access the child page's DOM from the parent page. SO has security policies that prevent normal iframe functionality. To review a working example, see this [**<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>**](http://embed.plnkr.co/VbtXSKmUXSrmU09OTyYi/) Details are commented in the Snippet and the Plunker.

**SNIPPET**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Parent Page</h1>
  <button style='display:block;'>Target Button in iFrame</button>
  <iframe src='child.html' width='350'></iframe>
  <script>
        /* Reference button
        || register click event on button
        || and call the function targetButton
        */
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', targetButton, false);

    function targetButton(e) {
      // Reference the iframe 
      var iFrm = document.querySelector('iframe');
      // Reference the document INSIDE the iframe 
      var iDoc = iFrm.contentWindow.document;
      // Reference the button INSIDE the iframe's document 
      var iBtn = iDoc.querySelector('.dl-btn');
      // Do whatever you want to iBtn 
      iBtn.style.color = '#000000';
      iBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#FFCC22';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, the button is on the other page that's in the iframe, sorry for not clarifying it. Thanks for the answer, works perfectly!

Comment: @MohitBhasi that's great, very rarely do I see an OP follow through to resolve an iframe issue, They get frustrated and give up. Happy coding, sir. 

Comment: Try, try, try till you succeed they say. Happy coding!